# (Javascript) Firebase error, write multiple times to the database automatically after reconnect to internet

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to code something which allows we do store data into the database when the internet is available and also when the user disconnected and reconnects again. I tried to use the sample code to help me with this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
  <!-- This is a wide open CSP declaration. To lock this down for production, see below. -->
  <!--/meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" /-->
  <!--/meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
    default-src *;
    style-src * 'unsafe-inline';
    script-src * 'unsafe-inline';
   "/-->
  <!--/External/-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  <title>DeeLight</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="clickButton" type="submit"> Submit</button>
  <div id="result"></div>

  
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.5/firebase.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyD41Ig37DIfH-MoF04cO4MYbcTYKL_wErQ",
      authDomain: "fypfirebase.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://fypfirebase.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "fypfirebase",
      storageBucket: "fypfirebase.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "787149952533"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    // since I can connect from multiple devices or browser tabs, we store each connection instance separately
// any time that connectionsRef's value is null (i.e. has no children) I am offline
var myConnectionsRef = firebase.database().ref('users/004/connections');

// stores the timestamp of my last disconnect (the last time I was seen online)
var lastOnlineRef = firebase.database().ref('users/004/lastOnline');

var connectedRef = firebase.database().ref('.info/connected');
connectedRef.on('value', function(snap) {
         $("#clickButton").on("click", function writeUserData() {
  if (snap.val() === true) {
    // We're connected (or reconnected)! Do anything here that should happen only if online (or on reconnect)
    var con = myConnectionsRef.push();

    // Add this device to my connections list
    // this value could contain info about the device or a timestamp too
    con.set(true);

    // When I disconnect, update the last time I was seen online
    lastOnlineRef.onDisconnect().set(firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
  }
});
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Basically, I create a button, data will be stored in the database (after clicking the button)when the internet is available.
Data can store into the database. When there is no internet and I clicked the button, the data will be stored in the database when *after reconnected*.

The problem comes when I click again (after reconnected), the function seems triggered two times. when I disconnect and reconnect again.. it triggered three times.

[Click to see the generated result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r13wa.png)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

creating a onclick event inside a firebase on() stream just yells trouble to me can you try make these two independent and use a variable to track online status?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
  <!-- This is a wide open CSP declaration. To lock this down for production, see below. -->
  <!--/meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" /-->
  <!--/meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
    default-src *;
    style-src * 'unsafe-inline';
    script-src * 'unsafe-inline';
   "/-->
  <!--/External/-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  <title>DeeLight</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="clickButton" type="submit"> Submit</button>
  <div id="result"></div>

  
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.5/firebase.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyD41Ig37DIfH-MoF04cO4MYbcTYKL_wErQ",
      authDomain: "fypfirebase.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://fypfirebase.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "fypfirebase",
      storageBucket: "fypfirebase.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "787149952533"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    // since I can connect from multiple devices or browser tabs, we store each connection instance separately
// any time that connectionsRef's value is null (i.e. has no children) I am offline
var myConnectionsRef = firebase.database().ref('users/004/connections');

// stores the timestamp of my last disconnect (the last time I was seen online)
var lastOnlineRef = firebase.database().ref('users/004/lastOnline');

var connectedRef = firebase.database().ref('.info/connected');
var connectionStatus = false;
connectedRef.on('value', function(snap) {
     connectionStatus=snap.val()
     if(connectionStatus)
     {
      lastOnlineRef.onDisconnect().set(firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
     }
});

$("#clickButton").on("click", function writeUserData() {
  if (connectionStatus) {
    // We're connected (or reconnected)! Do anything here that should happen only if online (or on reconnect)
    var con = myConnectionsRef.push();
    con.set(true);
    
  }
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```